# Generating a QuestionID Using a Nested Loop for a Quiz Game

Tags: c#, unity3d

So I started learning OOs and code refactoring and decided to do some project. It just some simple quiz game.

Here are some mechanics

- There are 3 sets
- Each set have 8 Brands (types)
- Each brand have 10 questions

So what I did was this

**Set Class**

```
public class Set{
    public string setName;
    public Brand[] brands;
}
```

**Brand Class**

```
public class Brand{
    public string brandName;
    public Question[] questions;
}
```

**Question Class**

```
public class Question {
    public string question;
    public string[] choices = new string[3];  //choices for each question
    public string correctAnswer;  //will hold the correct answer for a question

    public string questionID(){
       // making a id for question
        string qID = "";

        qID += question + "|";

        foreach(string choice in choices){
            qID += choice + "|";
        }

        qID += correctAnswer + "|";

        qID += fontSize;

        return qID;
    }

}
```

So what I need is to create some kind of id for each question, what I did is this

```
public class QuestionManager : MonoBehaviour {
public void saveToDB(){
    int setID = 0;
      foreach(Set set in sets){

          int brandID = 0;
          foreach(Brand brand in set.brands){

              int questionID = 0;
             foreach(Question question in brand.questions){


                string questionKey = "s" + setID + "|" + "b" + brandID + "|" + "q" + questionID;
                string questionAnswer =  "value:"+ set.setName + "|" + brand.brandName + "|" + question.questionID() ;

                PlayerPrefs.SetString(
                key: questionKey,
                value: questionAnswer
                );  // save to the database

                questionID++; 
          }
            brandID++;
          }
          setID++;
      }

}
}
```

I'm really curious if there are some good refactoring for this kind of loop. Also I should add that I'll be using this ids for getting the questions later.

Comment: Before anyone can write any review we must know what your code is doing. Currently we only know it's quiz. Could you explain how it works by [edit]ing your quesiton and adding this information to it?

Comment: I tried adding comments and more description. This is simply a code for making questionId. And use that id to navigate the questions later.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: `saveToDB` is supposed to save something to a database, right? Why isn't it doing anything then? You are creating a string that is never used anywhere...

Comment: There I added the codes. I thought that will be enough since I'm just here asking for the nested loop refactoring.

Comment: Well, you're asking for code improvement suggestions ;-] it can be anything and if your code isn't complete, does not compile or doesn't do anything useful then it's off-topic. Have you removed any more parts or is that all?

Comment: Ah I see will note that for my future questions.

Yep that is all. There are still removed parts but those are just empty methods that don't have any codes inside, I just declared them so that I'll remember to implement them later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask for a refactoring of the current method. It could be:

```
public void saveToDB()
{
  int setID = 0;
  foreach (Set set in sets)
  {
    int brandID = 0;
    foreach (Brand brand in set.brands)
    {
      int questionID = 0;
      foreach (Question question in brand.questions)
      {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(
          key: $"s{setID}|b{brandID}|q{questionID}",
          value: $"value:{set.setName}|{brand.brandName}|{question.questionID()}"); // save to the database

        questionID++;
      }
      brandID++;
    }
    setID++;
  }
}
```

Here is used string interpolation `$"s{setID}...."` instead of string concatenation which is considered to be bad practice because it results in too many string instantiations and is hard to read.

---

It could be done by using LINQ, but that is maybe more confusing and will actually be slower:

```
public void saveToDB()
{
  var questionInfos = sets.SelectMany((set, setId) => set.brands.SelectMany((brand, brandId) => brand.questions.Select((question, questionId) => new { key = $"s{setId}|b{brandId}|q{questionId}", value = $"value:{set.setName}|{brand.brandName}|{question.questionID()}" })));

  foreach (var questionInfo in questionInfos)
  {
    PlayerPrefs.SetString(questionInfo.key, questionInfo.value);
  }
}
```

Just for the sport, it can be done in inline query syntax (with a little help from method syntax) as t3echb0t suggested:

```
public void saveToDB()
{
  var questionInfos = from setAndId in sets.Select((set, id) => (set, id))
                      from brandAndId in setAndId.set.brands.Select((brand, id) => (brand, id))
                      from questionAndId in brandAndId.brand.questions.Select((question, id) => (question, id))
                      select new
                      {
                        key = $"s{setAndId.id}|b{brandAndId.id}|q{questionAndId.id}",
                        value = $"value:{setAndId.set.setName}|{brandAndId.brand.brandName}|{questionAndId.question.questionID()}"
                      };

  foreach (var questionInfo in questionInfos)
  {
    PlayerPrefs.SetString(questionInfo.key, questionInfo.value);
  }
}
```

---

That said, I would consider an mandatory Id to be a property on each `Set, Brand and Question` instance:

```
public abstract class ObjectBase
{
  public ObjectBase(string name, int id)
  {
    Name = name;
    Id = id;
  }

  public string Name { get; }
  public int Id { get; }
}

public class Set : ObjectBase
{
  public Set(string name, int id) : base(name, id)
  {

  }

  public Brand[] Brands { get; set; }
}

public class Brand : ObjectBase
{
  public Brand(string name, int id) : base(name, id)
  {

  }

  public Question[] Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question : ObjectBase
{
  public int FontSize;
  public string[] Choices = new string[3];  //choices for each question
  public readonly int CorrectAnswerId;  //will hold the correct answer for a question

  public Question(string question, int correctAnswerId, string[] choices, int id) : base(question, id)
  {
    CorrectAnswerId = correctAnswerId;
    Choices = choices;
  }

  public string TheQuestion => Name;

  public string QuestionID()
  {
    // making a id for question
    return $"{TheQuestion}|{string.Join("|", Choices)}|{CorrectAnswerId}|{FontSize}";
  }

}


public class QuestionManager //: MonoBehaviour
{
  Set[] sets = new Set[0];

  public void saveToDB()
  {
    foreach (Set set in sets)
    {
      foreach (Brand brand in set.Brands)
      {
        foreach (Question question in brand.Questions)
        {
          PlayerPrefs.SetString(
            key: $"s{set.Id}|b{brand.Id}|q{question.Id}",
            value: $"value:{set.Name}|{brand.Name}|{question.QuestionID()}"); // save to the database
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice here that there is no point in calling the name of a `Set` "`setName` - `Name` is sufficient.
Further notice that it is common practice in C# to use `PascalCase` for public members.

The benefit of having the entities be born with an id, is that you can use that id to identify each instance uniquely throughout the session/lifetime of each object. And as shown the `key/value-pair` for `PlayerPrefs.SetString` is easier created.

Comment: If you write linq in a single line like you did then it's a sure thing it's confusing ;-P in cases with multiple `SelectMany` the query syntax is much more readable - of course only when you use line breaks ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t: I'm not that used to write inline queries, and I'm not sure how to include an index. If you know how feel free to add to my answer.

Comment: Nah, maybe another time with a better quesiton. I don't feel like figuring out what `sets` is - I told OP to provide everything but they refused so I don't care - almost forgot to give a +1 for actually doing this ;-)